# Alternative Understanding of Euclid Book 1 Proposition 16

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

Looking at the [proof of Euclid Book 1 Proposition 16](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI16.html), it seems to me that if we were to know for certain that CF, AB were parallel, then the equality of ∠BAE and ∠ECF would follow from them being alternate angles formed when a line crosses two parallel lines.

[image]

I'm pretty confident that CF, AB are parallel, but I'm sure sure how to prove the assertion. Also, I wonder if there is any reason to prefer the original proof over this approach if it is valid?

Comment: Well, you can deduce that those lines are parallel *from* the equality of the angles.  I don't see any natural way to go in the opposite order and prove they are parallel first, though.  Moreover, to go from the parallel lines to equal angles requires the parallel postulate, which Euclid is still avoiding at this point.

Comment: Also, all the results relating parallel lines and angles are proved *after* this proposition in Euclid (and some of them use it), so invoking them here would be circular for Euclid.

Comment: As a general rule, if you want to understand why Euclid uses the proofs he does, you should read the Elements from the beginning and see the progression of results he is building up.  Many approaches that might look intuitively natural end up being circular.

Comment: Why to prefer Euclid's order: the parallel postulate (parallel lines don't intersect) doesn't have to be true, other geometries arise if you replace that with intersection or divergence. Euclid may have suspected that the postulate was shaky and his logical organization defers use of that postulate about as long as possible in considering triangle properties, presumably in order to build the biggest foundation without invoking it.